# how to add onclick event to start timer

Tags: javascript, onclick, mouseevent

New to coding. Created a timer that I would like to start when "gameStart" button is pushed, instead of on page load. Not sure where to insert my "onclick". Thank you

```
<div id= "startButtons">
        <button  id= "gameStart">Get Going!</button>

<script>

var timeleft = 15;

var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + 
"&nbsp"+"seconds remaining";

  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is up!"
  }
}, 1000);

    console.log(countdown);

</script>
```

Comment: Let me assure you that you are not the first person ever creating a timer in JavaScript.  Please use your favorite search engine and you will find tons of examples.

Comment: It would be good if you post the question after searching a few existing solutions. Btw welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add an Event Listener click function to your div.

Heres some working code:

```js
document.getElementById("gameStart").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var timeleft = 15;

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + 
    "&nbsp"+"seconds remaining";

    timeleft -= 1;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is up!"
    }
    }, 1000);

    console.log(countdown);
});
```

```html
        <div id= "startButtons">
          <button  id= "gameStart">Get Going!</button>
        </div>
        <div id= "countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `onclick` event on the button.

```html
<div id= "startButtons">
  <button  id= "gameStart" onclick="">Get Going!</button>
</div>
```

Then you have to modify your function to not start before the click.

```js
var timeleft = 15;

// global variables for reference
var downloadTimer;

function startInterval() {  // everything inside this function that is called with click on button
  downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + "&nbsp"+"seconds remaining";

    timeleft -= 1;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is up!"
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the **onclick on the button**, a simple modification to your code will help you in achieving what you wanted.

```
<p id="countdown"></p>
<div id= "startButtons">
    <button onclick="sample()" id= "gameStart">Get Going!</button>

<script>

var timeleft = 15;
function sample() {
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function 
   function1(){ 
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + "&nbsp"+"seconds remaining";

timeleft -= 1;
if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);

document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is up!"
  }
}, 1000);

    console.log(countdown)
}

</script>
```